# Django compare data between a model and a mysql query

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, pymysql

In my django project i have a model with some field like thisone:

models.py

```
class UserComPfolio(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="User")
    p_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    p_year = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    p_descr = models.TextField()
    p_link = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.p_title
```

well, i have an external mysql db with a table with same table fields name,
I have to execute a query on that data and compare results with my models data, the mysql table is the master and i have adapt data in my model to data in mysql (add new rows, delete rows that does not exist anymore or modify it)
i use pymysql and do:

```
....
mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM u_customers")

myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

for x in myresult:
```

at this point i don't know what is the best way to compare and align my model to external table data

So many thanks in advance